# Issue with Instantiating MultiLevel Inheritance in Python

Tags: python

In a particular sequence of a test case, there is a `TypeError: __init__` error.

When I run this code with TestCode 3 before TestCode 2, there is a `TypeError: __init__`.

If I run TestCode 3 after Test Code 2, there is no error and output is displayed. Why?

CODE:

```
import datetime

class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name="", salary=0, job_desc="", doj=None):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.description = job_desc
        self.dataOfJoing = doj
        self.no_of_years = ""

    def calRaise(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        self.no_of_years = today.year - self.dataOfJoing.year
        if int(self.no_of_years) > 5:
            percent = 0.20
        else:
            percent = 0
        self.salary = self.salary + (self.salary * percent)

    def display(self):
        return "Employee: name = %s, Job description= %s, No of years= %s, " \
               "Salary = %s" % (self.name, self.description, self.no_of_years, self.salary)



class Server(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name="", salary=0, job_desc="", doj=None):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, salary, job_desc, doj)


class chef(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name="", salary=0, job_desc="", doj=None):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, salary, job_desc, doj)


class PizzaRobot(chef):

    def __init__(self):
        chef.__init__(self, "Robot",0,"cooks",datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 10))
```

## TestCode 1:

```
server = Server("John", 400, "customer interface", datetime.date(2015, 4, 3))

server.calRaise()

print(server.display())
```

## TestCode 3:

```
chef = chef("Tom", 5000, "makes food", datetime.datetime(2000, 8, 13))

chef.calRaise()

print(chef.display())
```

## TestCode 2:

```
robot = PizzaRobot()

robot.calRaise()

print(robot.display())
```

ERROR Message when TestCode 3 is run above TestCode 2:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/z10049/PycharmProjects/Q4Lab5/Q4.py", line 52, in 
>       robot = PizzaRobot()   File "/Users/z10049/PycharmProjects/Q4Lab5/Q4.py", line 38, in **init**
>       chef.**init**(self, "Robot",0,"cooks",datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 10)) TypeError: **init**() takes from 1 to 5 positional arguments but
>   6 were given

Comment: You created an **object** called `chef`. So `chef` now refers to that object, not to your class `chef`. This is why we give classes a capital letter.

Comment: chef.init is expecting 4 arguments and Robot sends it 4 values.

Comment: It's also why we use `super()` instead of hardcoding what class gets the `__init__` method.

Comment: The class was called chef and the object was also called chef. Thank you for spotting that!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you reuse the class name `chef` for the variable in this line:

```
chef = chef("Tom", 5000, "makes food", datetime.datetime(2000, 8, 13))
```

Then when you create the `PizzaRobot` object Python tries to call the `__init__` method on the object created above on this line:

```
chef.__init__(self, "Robot",0,"cooks",datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 10))
```

When Python calls a method on an object it automatically passes the object itself as the first argument to the method. So it will essentially change the call above to:

```
chef.__init__(self, self, "Robot",0,"cooks",datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 10))
```

That's why you're getting the error about 6 arguments instead of 5.

If you rename the class `chef` to `Chef` and keep the variable as `chef` you'll see that everything will work as it should.